# Why the remote branch is tracked but local branch has no upstream branch after push a local branch to remote git repo?

Tags: git

After push a local branch to remote WITHOUT --set-upstream parameter, I found the remote branch is tracked, but the local branch has no upstream branch. Aren't track and upstream the same meaning? what's difference if not?(git version 2.27.0.windows.1)

1. create branch

   $ git branch testing
2. push local branch to remote

   $ git checkout testing

   $ git push origin testing
3. push changes, but looks like no upstream at all.

   $ git push

   **fatal: The current branch testing has no upstream branch.
   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
   git push --set-upstream origin testing**
4. but in the detail of remote origin, the remote branch testing is tracked.
   [image]

What's the difference between tracked and upstream? I doesn't understand current status: the remote branch tracked but the local branch has no upstream.

Comment: Run `git config -l` before and after `git push origin -u testing` and compare the 2 outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you display is the output of `git remote show`.

See @torek's explanations here :
[“git remote show origin”: why all branches show “tracked” even when some aren't?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379132/86072)

Wiith this command, "tracked" means that the branch will be downloaded to a local `origin/*` ref (note : this is not explicitly stated in the docs, and is indeed misleading).

If you want to see "what local branch tracks what remote branch" :

use `git branch -vv`, or check the content of your `.git/config` (`git config -l | grep branch` or `git config --get-regexp '^branch\.'`)

Comment: Clearly. Thank you！

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** your *local* branch isn't tracking a remote yet, but your *remote* copy is tracking the branch on origin.

**Details:**

There are 3 buckets:

1. Your local branch.
2. Your copy of the remote branch.
3. The actual remote branch.

Setting your local branch to "track" an upstream branch links #1 and #2. From the remote's point of view, "tracked" means #2 exists and is linked to #3.

In the context of the command:

```
git remote show origin
```

"tracked" means that you have a copy of that branch in your copy of the remote. Note if someone else adds a branch and you haven't fetched it yet, instead of "tracked" you will see "new". When you pushed out your local branch for the first time, your *remote* branch began tracking origin's branch, but you didn't set your local copy to track the remote branch. Had you done "push -u" you would have also set the upstream tracking branch to the remote.